# Rails nested attributes in department store pattern not autosaving foreign key

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In the following "department store pattern" I have three models:

```
class Store
  has_many :items, inverse_of: :store, autosave: true
  has_many :departments, inverse_of: :store, autosave: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :departments, allow_destroy: true

class Department
  belongs_to :store, inverse_of: :departments
  has_many :items, autosave: true, inverse_of: department
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, allow_destroy: true

class Item
  belongs_to :store, inverse_of: :items
  belongs_to :department, inverse_of: :items
```

When I try the following:

```
store = Store.new
department = store.departments.build
item = department.items.build

store.save
```

Then the item does not associate with the store.

My solution to the problem was to add the following to the Item model:

```
class Item
  before_validation :capture_store_info
  def capture_store_info
    self.store = self.department.store
  end
```

I added it to the before_validation callback because in my non-trivial code I have a bunch of validations, including one that checks for the presence of the store model.

Question: My solution works, but is it the correct (ie. Rails conventional) way of solving this problem?  Is there a better solution.  This feels kinda dirty, and every time I have done something in Rails that felt "kinda dirty" it has come back to bite me later.

Thanks,
JB